# how to create a server which can reply to a SMS from cell phone and search relevant information back to that number?

Tags: sql-server, network-programming

i want to develop a system in which we can store our passwords of different accounts or ATM etc thought a website in a database (cell number will be the primary key)to a server. this information need to be accessed by the user from its cell phone by sending a message and its should reply the saved password to that number back. now problems are 1) how to set up a server? 2)how to send a message from cell to pc? 3) how to reply back from pc to cell?

Answer (score 0):

I think your biggest problem is doing this securely. If someone forgets their password, a safer alternative is to have them reset it after confirming their identity.

However, if you want to look into this further, a quick Google search yielded this result: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/2bdeb3c6-9945-4804-a9bc-0d53704d35da/